# Python Quandl output in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, quandl

[VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2XKl.png)

How can I see the output of this code?

There is no error as you can see but I don't know how to see output?

Should I write it on Jupyter or sth else ?

Comment: [Please don't include your code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Instead, please [edit] your question to include your code as [formatted text](/editing-help#code).

Comment: The output of code is shown in **Terminal**, why do you insist on showing it below **OUTPUT**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The result is shown in **Terminal** by default, please check it in **Terminal**:
[image]